# How to display message on pattern validation?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I added pattern attribute to template

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="elementName"
                                   [(ngModel)]="elementName" name="elementName"
                                   (input)="onElementNameChanged()" #name="ngModel" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9_)*\S]*" >
```

How to add message to display if input is not correct?

Something like wont work:

```
<div [hidden]="!name.errors.pattern"
     class="alert alert-danger">
     Name must match pattern
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use `ReactiveForms` instead of `TemplateDrivenForms` as they are really good to manage validation patterns and messages.

**An HTML snippet example :**

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="user" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div formGroupName="account">

      <md-input-container>
        <input md-input type="text" placeholder="{{'USER.EMAIL' | translate}} *" formControlName="email" autocomplete="off">
        <md-hint class="error" *ngIf="user.get('account.email').hasError('required') && user.get('account.email').touched">
          {{'VALIDATOR.EMAIL_RQ' | translate}}
        </md-hint>
        <md-hint class="error" *ngIf="user.get('account.email').hasError('pattern') && user.get('account.email').touched">
          {{'VALIDATOR.WRONG_EMAIL' | translate}}
        </md-hint>
      </md-input-container>

      <md-input-container>
        <input md-input type="password" placeholder="{{'USER.PASSWORD' | translate}} *" minlength="6" formControlName="password" autocomplete="off">
        <md-hint class="error" *ngIf="user.get('account.password').hasError('required') && user.get('account.password').touched">
          {{'VALIDATOR.PWD_RQ' | translate}}
        </md-hint>
      </md-input-container>

    </div>

    <button md-raised-button [disabled]="!user.valid || submitted" color="accent" type="submit" class="submit-button">
      {{'LOGIN.BUTTON' | translate}}
    </button>

  </form>
```

This HTML example shows a login form with validation. Note how the `md-hint` elements **show only when the form has the validation errors on the specific fields**.

You can actually set an interface to match your `ReactiveForm`.
Here is the interface linked to the example :

```
export interface Account {
  account: {
    email: string;
    password: string;
  }
}
```

**The TypeScript example snippet :**

```
  import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
  import { EmailRegex } from 'app/shared/shared.interface'; // Imported regex for validator


  ...

  user: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    ...

    // Init your reactive form
    this.user = this.formBuilder.group({
      account: this.formBuilder.group({
        email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(EmailRegex)]],
        password: ['', Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }
```

Please note how the **form groups** match the **interface**. Also, you can set the form values there if you want to, but as you can see my fields `email` and `password` are set with an empty string value.
Note that you can also add as much validators as you want in the array linked to the field.

You can then access your form values on `submit()` directly from your primary `FormGroup` :

```
this.user.value.account.email
```

---

If this example wasn't good enough, I strongly suggest you read Todd Motto's guide on `ReactiveForms` which is really well explained :

https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-reactive

Comment: Be aware that I use the https://material.angular.io/ library, hence the reason why I have `md-name` html elements. So your `md-hint` will probably be a simple `div`

Comment: thank you, but I need to validate TemplateDrivenForms since I already have that one in my project.

Comment: It's just a different form, but it will allow you to make what you want work. You juste have to change this form and it will work as a charm, even if you have other template driven forms in your app

Comment: I am aware of reactive forms, but i cannot change this form from template driven to reactive. I had to add validation across the project for a lot of template-driven forms.

Comment: I actually found on the net that you can add some custom Classes for your validators, but it seemed to be very costly for something that should be basic for forms. Instead I changed all the forms to Reactives ones. It is actually pretty fast to change them. It's up to you after that